# Array Compression Algorithm

Tags: c, compression

I have an array of 10345 bytes, I want to compress the array and then decompress, kindly suggest me the compression algorithm which can reduce the size of array. I am using c language, and the array is of unsigned char type.

Rephrased: Can someone suggest a general-purpose compression algorithm (or library) for C/C++?

Comment: Voted close: not a real question.

Comment: @Heath, what is the real question?

Comment: @Heath: You seem a bit close itchy today.

Comment: Arman: The answer does not depend on the size of the data, but on what sort of content it is.  This is not a real programming question.  You need to understand how various compression algorithms work, and why some are better suited to particular data than others.

Comment: @Arman: Please expand on your question. What is in this array you want to compress? What language, etc?

Comment: @Heath: It's still a programming question is he can give us the language and data type.

Comment: @Heath Hinnucutt: Recommended ways to cure bad mood: 0. Shutting down PC 1. Using punching bag 2. Sprinting for a few miles. 3. Weight lifting.

Comment: This "everybody is a moron" routine is getting old.

Comment: I don't recall the last time WinZip asked me what type of data I was going to compress. And if an algorithm decides internally the best compression strategy by first analyzing the data then why can't that be part of the algorithm?

Comment: @Paul: because storing which algorithm is used takes space. Even such an adaptive compressor that selects an algorithm based on the data will result in enlargement rather than shrinking for most of the input space.

Comment: @Heath If people knew what they were talking about, they wouldn't really have to ask questions about it, now would they?

Comment: @Tyler: Ask questions is one thing.  Answer questions is another.  Q: "How do I compress 10,345 bytes?"  A: "Use zlib and read Wikipedia"  Reward: 115 credibility points.  Reeeediculous!  Give the points to Wikipedia, maybe?

Comment: @Hans - As far as I recall, the only person I've called a moron (GMan) on SO called me a moron first.  Do you have a specific example otherwise?

Comment: @Tyler: Asking questions is one thing.  I was referring to the people who *answer* questions like this one as those who have credibility which reflects actual ignorance.

Comment: I have to agree with Heath. That's not a response as the question was incomplete, to put it mildly. Maybe the OP shouldn't even consider compression, it's probably the wrong approach. If it's sparsly populated array maybe a list or a tree would be a better data structure, if it's "random" data a generic compressor will not be able to compress anyway or anything else. The question lacks info to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Arman - I am so sorry.  I never saw that you asked me "what is the real question?"  What is missing from your question, mostly, is information about the *nature* of the data.  The length of the data to be compressed is a really unimportant sidenote.  But information on what inherent redundancy the compression could be expected to exploit... that is relevant. Your data may have redundancies that Zlib would never detect, but which you can accomodate in your own code.  For an extreme example, instead of sending a compressed picture of a fractal, send only the input parameters which generate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)
[Lossless Compression Algorithms](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Multimedia/node207.html)

Comment: @SigTerm -- Oh, it's unsigned char.  I guess that means the contents of the unsigned char array is compressible by Zlib.  Gosh, I had no idea.

Comment: @Hans - Oh, yes, it does.  Use zlib ever?

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: Dude, I really recommend spriting/punching bag. Way more exciting.

Comment: @SigTerm: What with your username, I would expect you to tell me to "handle myself" for stress relief.  :)  By the way, in 1960, US government psychiatrist Eric Berne found that people who sublimate via violence are prone to homicide.  So I'll pass on the punching bag.

Comment: -1 I have to agree with Heath. That's not a response as the question was incomplete, to put it mildly. Maybe the OP shouldn't even consider compression, it's probably the wrong approach. If it's sparsly populated array maybe a list or a tree would be a better data structure, if it's "random" data a generic compressor will not be able to compress anyway or anything else. The question lacks info to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @tristopia -- Careful, man, you don't want to be on the wrong side of the SO popularity contest by accident.  ;)

Comment: I don't really care about popularity and saying to someone that his question is bad and explaining why is the right thing to do. Giving any answer that has a good chance of being inadequate is wrong. People should introspect why they're contributing to SO, to exchange know-how or to participate in a juvenile pissing conquest.

Comment: @tristopia - I went back to all your answers and I saw they are all good answers.  So there you have 65 up votes from me.  Many of your answers are seriously under-voted, too.  I did not spread out the voting, not trying to abuse the system, so you only get 200 rep.

Comment: Thank you that's nice, but apparently someone just undid that as I'm back to 809 reps.

Comment: @Heath I would have thought that people who used punching bags are LESS prone to homicide, seeming as they are better practised in self defence?

Comment: @Tom - Sublimators are prone to *commit* homicide, not fall victim to it.  The "Tough Guy" mentality is document in Eric Berne, Games People Play.

Answer (score 3):

This post's a community wiki.  I don't want any points for this -- I've already voted to close the question.

The number of bytes to compress has very little to do with choice of compression algorithm, although it does affect the implementation.  For example, when you have fewer than 2^15 bytes to compress, if you are using ZLib, you will want to specify a compression-level of less than 15.  The compression-level in Zlib (one of the two such parameters) controls the depth of the "look-back" dictionary.  If your file is shorter than 16k bytes, then a 32k look-back dictionary will never half-fill; in that case, use one less bit of pointer into the look-back for a 1/15th edge on the compression compared to setting ZLib to "max."

The content of the data is what matters.  If you are sending images with mostly background, then you might want Run Length Encoding (used by Windows .BMP, for example).

If you are sending mostly English text, than you wish you could use something like ZLib, which implements Huffman encoding and LZW-style look-back dictionary compression.

If your data has been encrypted, then attempting to compress it will not succeed.

If your data is a particular type of signal, and you can tolerate some loss of detail, then you may want to transform it into frequency space and send only the principal components.  (e.g., JPEG, MP3)

Comment: So you vote to close, and then submit an answer? Confusing at best Heath.

Comment: @Josh -- My answer is essentially an explanation of *why* I voted to close.  If you read my answer, you'll see that it is very vague and general.  As any answer to such a question needs to be.  The OP didn't even specify if he wanted lossless, although that's a fair assumption...

Comment: @Heath: Then this should be a comment because it is **not** an answer (by my judgment and your admission).

Comment: @Josh - No, I did not say it's not an answer.  It is an answer.  And if you read it, you may learn something.  But it is not *only* an answer to the question.  It is an answer to the meta-question of "what the heck am [OP] talking about?"  So, no, not by my own admission.  Only by your "judgment," which is a great admission on your part.  Also your judgment is clearly biased by your opinion of me.  Objectively, the text above *does* answer OP.  So take your judgment and self-handle it.

Comment: @Heath: "Very vague and general" answers are discouraged. Answers which the author describes as "essentially an explanation of why I voted to close" are also discouraged. If you feel this could possibly be a meta answer **put it on meta, not SO**.

Comment: @Josh: Look at the two answers here.  Which of the two answers is more vague and general?  Can you be serious?  As for meta, that is for discussion of SO, not discussion of SO questions.  Surely, you already know that?  Being disingenuous or something?

Comment: This is actually a far better answer than the other one - the key part being *"The number of bytes to compress has very little to do with choice of compression algorithm ... The content of the data is what matters."* .  In a sense there *are* no general purpose compression algorithms - just expansion algorithms that have interesting failure cases.

Comment: @Josh: I do realize I criticized my own answer as "very vague and general."  ANY answer to this poorly-posed question must be "very vague and general."  THAT is why I voted close.  But if SO insists this question must live on in the corpus for reference, at least the answer should say *something* useful.